# How to limit Chromium to load one tab at a time?

Tags: chromium

I have some folders of bookmarks that I would like to open all at once, glance at, and close if there's no attention needed.

I used to manually click each one, re-opening the folder every time and re-using the same tab, until I found the right-click menu option to `Open all (#)`, where `#` is the number of tabs that will try to load all at once.  There are options to do that in the same window, a new window, or a new Incognito window, but they always load in parallel, which slows them down on a limited connection.

I'm sure the connection could keep up with me if it would only load the first one, then load the second while I'm looking at the first, etc.  As it is, loading all of them together, it takes a long time before *any* of them is ready, and soon after that, they're *all* done and I'm still looking at the first.

Is there a way to load a bunch of tabs ***sequentially***, so I only have to wait for the first one and the rest are in the background?
(I suspect that it'll be loading the 5th or so while I'm looking at the 2nd, but you get the idea.)

---

Fully updated with `sudo apt {update|full-upgrade|autoremove}` and rebooted.
Chromium `Version 92.0.4515.98 (Official Build) Built on Raspbian , running on Raspbian 10 (32-bit)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about (or use) Chromium but Vivaldi lets you stack tabs,  open groups of tabs, open each link in a new tab, open saved links in a new window and more.

I originally tried this from a suggestion on the Raspberry Pi website and now use it on all platforms. It has the added advantage of syncing settings across machines (which Chromium now refuses to do).

Comment: I was under the impression that the Pi had some...special...hardware, and that the only browser to effectively use it was the default Chromium that comes preinstalled.  Thus, anything else has a performance hit because it hasn't been modified to work specifically on the Pi.  That may have changed now, but I've never had much reason to look.  Until now, possibly.

Comment: Also, this answer doesn't address the question at all.  It offers an alternative browser - a "frame-challenge", which is also welcome - and the reasons are fine as far as they go, but the specific one that I'm asking about is not among them.